# Split spinner data when item selected

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, spinner

I am using spinner.Add("heading"+23) for adding item to spinner, and it shows heading23 in spinner list. How may I get data back in two variables (one for heading and one for int value).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: show exact code you are using. in current case you use only constants, so you don't need to do anything to split it back. You can use same constants

Comment: Please explain the question little more. And add some of your code

Comment: ArrayList bookmarkPages;
bookmarkPageReference pageRef = new bookmarkPageReference("Test",pageNo);
db.Insert(pageRef);
var table = db.Table<bookmarkPageReference>();
bookmarkPages = new ArrayList();
bookmarkPages.Add("Book Marked Pages");
foreach (var item in table)
    {
     pageRef = new bookmarkPageReference(item.heading, item.pageNumber);
     bookmarkPages.Add(pageRef);
    }
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, AD_Spinner.Resource.Layout.spinner_item, bookmarkPages);
    sp.Adapter = adapter;
    sp.ItemSelected += sp_itemSelected;

Comment: Here is my code, I am taking two values from database and showing on spinner, when I get back it returns string. I want to take values in two variables

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon where are you ?

Comment: @Umair: use [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41278837/edit) button to add your details to the question instead of adding it into comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly. You want to split strings like "heading23" back into "heading" and "23".

If so, you can leverage [Regular Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx). In C#, there is a class [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-MonoAndroid,Version%3Dv7.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) for that you can use:

```
string str = "test123";
Regex reg = new Regex(@"\d+");//"\d" means digits "+" means match one or more
Match match=reg.Match(str);
if (match.Success)
{
    string numberStr =match.Value;//value="123"
    int number = int.Parse(numberStr);//number=123
    var title = str.Replace(numberStr, "");//title="test"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

When using java, spinner uses adapter. You can pass custom objects to that adapter. If I recall correctly, `toString` method is called for each item.

```
class MySpinnerDataItem {
    String title;
    int number;
}
```